# Has anyone noticed that the Windows Taskbar autohide stops working on more than one computer simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

The autohide feature on my Windows 7x64 stopped working on my home computer. I've tried moving it around top, left, right, bottom, unsetting and resetting the feature, but no luck.

I remoted in to my office computer, also Windows 7x64, and the same thing is happening there.

Comment: Have you checked the setting for hiding it?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "unsetting and resetting the feature".

Comment: Ah I missed that bit.  Sorry!  Restart do anything?

Comment: It's just weird that it started happening on both computers at the same time.

Comment: The planets lined up, this is the cause....